# TreeSet.tailSet returns SortedSet, said to be updatable vice versa but not when i code

Tags: java-8, set, treeset, ocpjp

I am trying to understand TreeSet.tailSet it was easy to implement but I am confused about the documentation :

> public SortedSet tailSet(E fromElement)
>   Description copied from interface: NavigableSet
>   Returns a view of the portion of this set whose elements are greater than or equal to fromElement. The returned set is backed by this set, so changes in the returned set are reflected in this set, and vice-versa. The returned set supports all optional set operations that this set supports.
>   The returned set will throw an IllegalArgumentException on an attempt to insert an element outside its range.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#tailSet(E)

it says

> he returned set is backed by this set, so changes in the returned set are reflected in this set, and vice-versa

but i dont see it working on my code testing

Note : this is for my OCPJP 8 preparation.

Here is my code snippet

```
System.out.println(" 3 floor : " + persons.floor(new Person("3Mark Anthony", "Ortiz")) +
    ", 3 ceiling : " + persons.ceiling(new Person("3Mark Anthony", "Ortiz")));

    System.out.println(" 5 higher : " + persons.higher(new Person("5Mark Anthony", "Ortiz")) );

    SortedSet<Person> personSet = persons.tailSet(new Person("3Mark Anthony", "Ortiz"));
    System.out.println(personSet.contains(new Person("3Mark Anthony", "Ortiz")));
    Person p3 = personSet.first();
    System.out.println(p3);
    System.out.println(persons.floor(new Person("3Mark Anthony", "Ortiz")).equals(p3));

    p3.firstName = "John Dave";

    System.out.println(p3);
    System.out.println(persons.floor(new Person("3Mark Anthony", "Ortiz")));
    System.out.println(personSet.first());

    persons.floor(new Person("3Mark Anthony", "Ortiz")).firstName = "Mike";
    System.out.println(p3);
    System.out.println(persons.floor(new Person("Mike", "Ortiz")));
```

and here is the output

```
3 floor : 2, 3 ceiling : 4
3 floor : [firstName:"3Mark Anthony", lastName: "Ortiz"], 3 ceiling : [firstName:"3Mark Anthony", lastName: "Ortiz"]
5 higher : [firstName:"6Mark Anthony", lastName: "Ortiz"]
true
[firstName:"3Mark Anthony", lastName: "Ortiz"]
true
[firstName:"John Dave", lastName: "Ortiz"]
[firstName:"2Mark Anthony", lastName: "Ortiz"]
[firstName:"John Dave", lastName: "Ortiz"]
[firstName:"John Dave", lastName: "Ortiz"]
[firstName:"Mike", lastName: "Ortiz"]
```

Now as you can see, I tried to update

```
p3.firstName = "John Dave";
```

and check it from its source Set object by

```
System.out.println(persons.floor(new Person("3Mark Anthony", "Ortiz")));
```

and still "3Mark Anthony" exist in the source set object. it was not update. and vice versa as you can see on the next line of codes.

Can someone help me understand what is wrong? I doubt javadoc missed it, it might be my understanding which is wrong.

PS. road to OCPJP 8

Comment: By “changes in the returned set” they mean changes via `add()`, `remove()` and similar methods. You are never allowed to change *elements* contained in a sorted set in a way that changes their ordering. Instead remove the element, change it and reinsert it.

Comment: PS You are preparing for *Oracle Certified Professional, Java SE 8 Programmer* but using the Java *7* documentation? You may want the [Java 8 API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#tailSet-E-) instead (not that there’s a difference in this case).

Comment: What do yo mean with “still "3Mark Anthony" exist in the source set object”?
 There is no evidence in your output for that. Well, the object that was formerly the `Person("3Mark Anthony", "Ortiz")` still exists as you didn’t remove it, but it has a different name. But you are asking for `persons.floor(new Person("3Mark Anthony", "Ortiz"))` and since there is no `3Mark …`, you get exactly what to expect, `2Mark…` which is “the greatest element in this set less than or equal to the given element”, which is how `floor` is defined. Surprisingly correct, given that you made the order inconsistent

Comment: @OleV.V. I think you are right :) I just realized thats what the javadoc means even in the java 8 doc version. :)  thank you very much for clearing it up :), for everyone thanks for sharing your thoughts.